# Scene Point of View Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

Okay, so I have a camera that is added to my vehicle and works on 3/4 of my levels. However, when I load the fourth level it throws this error code.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

```
func setupCamera() {
    vehicleCamera = SCNNode()
    vehicleCamera.position = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 30, -100)
    vehicleCamera.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: -(Float.pi / 16) * 2, y: Float.pi, z: 0)

    vehicleCamera.camera = SCNCamera()
    vehicleCamera.camera?.xFov = 60;
    vehicleCamera.camera?.zFar = 700;

    sceneView.pointOfView = vehicleCamera
}
```

The point that is highlighted is the following:

```
sceneView.pointOfView = vehicleCamera
```

So when trying to set the pointOfView it acts as if the vehicle camera no longer exists as a pointer. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traced the issue back to the levels physics body. When setting the level as static with a concave geometry it crashes xCode. The camera was not the issue at all in this case. The camera was added after the level and because the level had a poor physics geometry it threw a bad access exec on the next node added to the scene.